# where to publish web service?

Tags: web-services

Where we need to deploy or publish wsdl so that consumer can get the service?

Comment: do we need to publish In UDDI site ?

Answer (score 2):

On a Web Server that the consumer is able to access.

If you're not ready to publish anything to the server yet, you could also simply send them the WSDL file (via email, etc.) so they can start developing against it without having the services ready to be called.

Comment: I have read that we can publish in UDDI registry.But i dont know how n wer to publish?